# c++ cmake ( converting windows to platform indepedent ) WinExec to execute_process

Tags: c++, cmake

getting c++ error like identifier execute_proces not found

```
'''
void p1::imp2(std::string commandttorun)
    {
        //WinExec(commandttorun.c_str(), SW_SHOWNORMAL);  
        set(EXECUTE_COMMAND commandttorun.c_str()); 
       execute_process(COMMAND ${EXECUTE_COMMAND}  RESULT_VARIABLE rv); 
}'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write CMake code in your C++ source code.
The two are not interchangeable.

One is a programming language that is compiled using a C++ compiler. The other is a build system language interpreted by the CMake application.

If you want to write cross platform C++, it's worth investigating libraries that implement this type of platform dependent functionality. Another alternative is providing a POSIX and Windows implementation, which will get your code working on most operating systems, but will cost you double in coding and maintenance.